# R perform arithmetic on multiple pairs of columns by name

Tags: r

I'd have a large dataset where I'd like to find the difference between pairs of columns. For example:

```
data<- data.frame(
A.a= c(1,2,3,4,5),
A.b= c(10,9,8,7,6),
A.c= c(5,5,5,5,5),
B.a= c(1,10,100,1000,10000),
B.b= c(2,20,200,2000,20000),
B.c= c(3,30,300,3000,30000))
```

I'd like to calculate 3 new separate columns for B.a - A.a, B.b - A.b, and B.c - A.c. Naturally I can do this individually for each column, but I can't find or fathom a solution that would automate the process for my dataset where I have 100+ pairs of columns.

A dplyr solution would be preferable if possible please.

Comment: You can't do any arithmetic on these columns - they are character vectors (you need to remove the quotation marks around your numbers). Also, please check that your example is reproducible (you haven't put commas after each argument in your call to `data.frame`. Please [edit] your question, and ensure that the code runs when you copy-paste it into your console. Thanks.

Comment: If the columns are in ordered blocks as you show, you can very simply do `data[4:6] - data[1:3]`. If you need to rely on names rather than column order, paste together column names for the same effect: `suffix = c("a", "b", "c")` then  `data[paste0("B.", suffix)] - data[paste0("A.", suffix)]`. If you want to use `dplyr`, I'd suggest you `pivot_longer` to create a `prefix` column with values `"A", "B"`, a suffix column with values `"a", "b", "c"`, and a value column with the numbers. You can than do `summarize(value[prefix == "B"] - value[prefix == "A"], .by = suffix)`

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks, have amended the example and it runs in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
## base, position-based
data[4:6] - data[1:3]
#    B.a   B.b   B.c
# 1    0    -8    -2
# 2    8    11    25
# 3   97   192   295
# 4  996  1993  2995
# 5 9995 19994 29995

## base, name-based
suffix = c("a", "b", "c")
data[paste0("B.", suffix)] - data[paste0("A.", suffix)]
#    B.a   B.b   B.c
# 1    0    -8    -2
# 2    8    11    25
# 3   97   192   295
# 4  996  1993  2995
# 5 9995 19994 29995

## tidyverse with pivots
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-id) |>
  separate_wider_delim(name, delim = ".", names = c("prefix", "suffix")) |>
  summarize(diff = value[prefix == "B"] - value[prefix == "A"], .by = c(id, suffix)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = suffix, values_from = diff)
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#      id     a     b     c
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     0    -8    -2
# 2     2     8    11    25
# 3     3    97   192   295
# 4     4   996  1993  2995
# 5     5  9995 19994 29995
```

Comment: Used the tidyverse solution, worked like a charm. Thank you